# how to use java based project in firebreath plugin framework

Tags: java, c++, plugins, firebreath

I am trying to develop a HTML5 plugin using NPAPI and firebreath framework. The code which needs to be used, is written in java but I need to convert it into C++. The only way i know is via JNI where i need to convert each .java file into .cpp file. However there are over 200 files in my project. Is there a better way to achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

Any "simple" way would be more of a c++ question than a plugin or firebreath question.  My guess is that you'd be far better off just making it an applet rather than a plugin if you want it mainly in java.  There is nothing that I'm aware of that will make it easy for you to do what you want to do using FireBreath or NPAPI directly.

Comment: Thanks @taxilian for your reply. My main task is to create a cross browser plugin and i am stuck in giving reference of a JAVA project. I am using firebreath to create the plugin in which I want to use some Java APIs. So, I want to know if my code in firebreath, which is mainly C++, can in any way use the Java APIs. The possible ways that i think is to either convert the Java project to C++(use JCC??) or by any other way the reference to java project can be given.

Comment: I believe I just answered that question.  to reiterate, I do not know of one, no.

Comment: I have similar needs and of course I have considered the option of using the Java Applet plugin but I have a lot of problems with it. Half the time it fail to load making the applet area permanently blank, other times it loads and crashes, and yet other times it freezes and consumes 100% CPU. I downloaded the sourcecode from IcedTea:s page and it have quite a lot of code, so the only problem I can identify are code bloat leading to maintenance problems. The solution would be migrate the code from npapi to firebreath but I suspect that writing a thin binding layer would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

JNI doesn't convert Java to C++, it is a technology for calling native code (such as C or C++) from Java code. It doesn't seem relevant to your problem: Either you (manually or robotically) convert all your Java to C++ (which you can then call from Firebreath), or you keep your code in Java and run an applet (with no C/C++ code involved.)
If an applet as suggested by @taxilian isn't a good choice, why not turn your Java project into an application, and have your Firebreath plugin launch that and communicate with it? Your plugin could even download and install the Java app, for example in a temp folder.  One limitation: The Java code won't have any direct access to internal browser API's, the Firebreath plugin would have to make any such calls on behalf of the Java app.  How hard this all is would mainly depend on the complexity and bandwidth of communication needed between the web page and the Java code.